# How else should I have asked my question in order to not get deleted

Tags: support, asking-questions

In [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/392659/how-to-implement-ci-cd-with-pl-sql) [image] I asked, I first got downvoted twice without having any clue where my mistake was. I've never minded downvoting, but if someone wants me to ask a question the right way, or ask a correct one, then I think they should let me see my mistake.

Anyway, after my first trial of correcting the question, I had a comment that I was not asking what I needed and that it was not clear what I wanted:

[image]

Then I edited the question and clearly asked what my concern was and sought an expert or at least an experienced answer.
I definitely showed in the steps of our usual process in detail and finally pointed out the part I was stuck. Then I found out that yet another downvote came and the question was deleted.

Comment: For those of us without 10k rep, could someone please copy the contents of the question here?

Comment: Note I commented the question before it got into its final shape - and I think Robert Harvey's action here - closing and deleting without any comment of what's so unclear even after the edit - is very debatable. I think the final version is quite clear (not that I have a good answer for you, but now I understand what you are after). Voting to reopen.

Comment: ... though I guess a good answer requires special expertise from Oracle DBAs. You will probably find the experts on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ . Oh, and I think your question title could be improved, it seems you are simply looking for a solution for automatic deployment, not a full-blown "CI/CD" process.

Comment: ... a quick search gave me [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157509/how-can-i-manage-pl-sql-package-source-at-the-method-level), which may be a starter for you (it essentially says, use packages as the smallest unit of deployment, not procedures).

Answer (score 3):

I might quibble over the close reason, but I'm not seeing that the core of your question is a good fit for the site.

I'll dive into the two main parts of your question on main:

> Currently, we tell DBA's verbally to take the version in the master and apply it to the production. How is that done if we try to automate it?

This is really going to be based upon whatever tooling you currently have in place.  Tool recommendations are explicitly off-topic for the site.

That said, we can throw that part of your question out.

> My main concern is the fact that when compiling PL/SQL objects, often several invalid objects occur and the DBA's interfere immediately. How can we manage this through automation?

This is what I think your real question is.  However, this implies to me that your test and pre-production environments are not identically structured as your production environment.  SQL scripts should behave exactly the same in production as they did in lower environments.

Beyond "don't do it", trying to automate manual intervention at this point in the SDLC is a very broad topic and not a good fit for the site's Q&A environment.

And an answer of "go fix your lower environments" isn't really an answer - it's a comment.  Future visitors would glean very little from a non-answer like that.

From your meta question:

> I definitely showed in the steps of our usual process in detail and finally pointed out the part I was stuck.

This is where I think you muddied your question on main.  Of the 7 paragraphs of text in your main question, only 2 are directly related to what you're trying to ask.  Providing just the right amount of background is an art, and unfortunately if you get it wrong it will negatively affect your question.

And looking back through the earlier revisions and the comments provided there, it appears to me that your question started at "unclear" as there certainly wasn't enough detail.  But it then went to "too broad" which is a risk with questions asking about SDLC process.

To address:

> How else should I have asked my question in order to not get deleted

I'm not sure that there's a good answer for you there.  Some questions simply aren't a good fit for the site's Q&A format.