# Question closed for duplicate - while the reason why I though the duplicate was not a duplicate is removed?

Tags: discussion

Well I had a question regarding releases and continuous delivery methods. Rightfully someone initialy showed the "same" question. However that question was about option "A" and "B", - and the answers also gave an option "C". while I was wondering about option "A" and "D", and how D compares to A.

[Topic here.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/393316/use-tags-or-branches-for-ci-release-builds-or-both)

Now I tried to explain this in an edit, however just now I notice the edit got removed and the question was closed as duplicate. - Without further explanation. An explanation where option "D" is discussed would be nice, since I cannot find any indication of that anywhere.

Comment: +1. This is just another abuse by powerful users and moderators.

Answer (score 3):

The "EDIT" paragraph was removed as it didn't contribute to your question. And it was just that one paragraph, the other two paragraphs were kept. Regardless, that paragraph didn't contain sufficient justification to reopen.

Having read your question, the duplicate, and most of the duplicate's answers, I'm not seeing how your proposed strategy isn't addressed through the duplicate Q. The top voted answers lay out some sound advice regarding branching strategy.

Your question needs to be edited to more clearly call out your branching strategy and what has already been addressed. And as an aside, there is no need to say "EDIT" in your edits. The revision history already captures that.

Comment: Well I explained that I'm using a third option not provided in the linked question: and I'm actually wondering *why* it is not considered.

Comment: @paul23 Then please edit your question on main and call out that difference.  Questions can be reopened after editing.

Comment: "So I'm wondering how would this [explained in paragraph above] system compare (in long term) to the proposed systems in the linked question." -- It was there before closing, and if there was a reason given "that system is equal to xyz if you consider a as b which you can do"; that would at least give me an indication. (Which I'd gladly accept).